# If an ant starts from A on a chessboard and can only move in the forward and upward direction, what is the number of ways in which it can reach B?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, chessboard

This is the chessboard, where A and B are the 2 ends of the board. An ant starts from end A, and can only move forwards (horizontally) and upwards (vertically). The ant **cannot** move diagonally and is not allowed to move backwards or be on a tile on more than one occasion. What is the number of ways in which the ant can reach the end B, from end A, on the chessboard?

[image]

My attempt:

[image]

I viewed each crossing as a $^2C_1$ scenario (to go either upward or forwards). We know that once the ant reaches the edge of the board, it can only go upward ie. only 1 option for movement is available. So I made cases for each leftmost horizontal tile the ant is on.

For crossing 8 tiles horizontally we have ${(^2C_1)}^{8}$.

In the first case, we go up by ${(^2C_1)}^{0})$. (0 tiles are travelled vertically along the 8 horizontal tiles).

In the second case, we go up by ${(^2C_1)}^{1}$ (1 tile is travelled vertically, somewhere along those 8 horizontal tiles).

In the third case, we go up by ${(^2C_1)}^{2}$ (2 tiles are travelled vertically, somewhere along those 8 horizontal tiles).

and so on. This sequence occurs 7 times as the ant is already on the 1st horizontal row of tiles.

Hence, the total sum is:

$$2^{8} + 2^{8}*2+ 2^{8}*2^{2}+ 2^{8}*2^{3}+ 2^{8}*2^{4}....+ 2^{8}*2^{7}$$

$$2^{8}(1 + 2^{1} + 2^{2} + .... 2^{7})$$

$$2^{8}(2^{7}-1)$$

$$256 \times 127$$

$$32512$$

We then multiply this number by 2, to account for those cases where the ant makes it journey till the **uppermost and leftmost** point of the board before proceeding forward to B.

Giving us,

$65024$

But it seems this answer is incorrect.
So how do you solve this intriguing Chessboard Permutation problem?

Comment: The ant must move right exactly $7$ times out of the $14$ moves (all other moves are up).  Thus the answer is $\binom {14}7=3432$, or have I misunderstood the rules?  Should say, I can't follow your calculation, and the proposed $280$ seems very far off.

Comment: I also think the answer should be $3432$. I think your calculation is probably counting some paths which walk off the top edge or off the right edge - your number is closer to "how many up-and-right paths are there of length $16$ on an infinite chessboard, with no constraints on where they end?".. but I can't really follow your logic, so I can't say for sure. Is $280$ perhaps the solution for a different problem? (long shot: there are $280$ ways to put two bishops on a chessboard so that they attack each other).

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes, it seems I made an error. 280 isn't the answer for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A correct path that joins $A$ to $B$ is made of $14$ steps, with $7$ steps up and $7$ steps right.

So basically, the question is : how many such paths are there ?

The answer is : in the $14$ steps, you just have to choose the $7$ ones where you go up ; the steps where you go right will be deduced immediately.

So there are $C_{14}^7$ such paths, which gives
$$3432 \text{ possibilities}$$